# AWStats Screen Sizes not showing in statistics

Tags: analytics, logging, awstats

[Awstats](http://www.awstats.org) 7.6 or 7.7 is not showing the screen sizes and the miscellaneous stats on the statistics page. 
I'm using IIS 7.5 on a Windows Server. 
All the parameters in the .conf file are correctly set:

```
MiscTrackerUrl="js/awstats_misc_tracker.js"
ShowScreenSizeStats=1
ShowMiscStats=anjdfrqwp
```

also the var awstatsmisctrackerurl is configured in the javascript file.
the result can be found in the log file in the column cs-uri-query for example:

```
screen=1000x1000&win=983x983&cdi=24&java=false&shk=n&svg=y&fla=n&rp=n&mov=n&wma=n&pdf=n&uid=awsuser_id1515617662100r7629&sid=awssession_id1515617662100r7629
```

How do I get this to work for IIS log files?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are using Awstat? The reason why I ask is that it is universally hated and considered the worst log analyzer on the market. I recommend Piwik which is one of the very best and absolutely free. When I was a web host, it was easy to install Awstat but I refused. It caused too many tech support calls trying to understand it. I used SawMill instead.

Comment: Piwik is now called Matomo, I will give it a try. I use several Log Analyzers, but AWStats works for me (apart from this feature...) Can't believe I'm the only one with this problem.

Comment: Almost no-one here is using Awstat. Thanks for the update on the name change. I still use SawMill, but expect to change to Matomo someday this year. It is far superior to SawMill in many ways and far less expensive! Cheers!!